# Vue 3 Not Displaying Data from Laravel 10 Backend in Notifications Dropdown

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-10

I'm developing an application using Laravel 10 as the backend and Vue 3 for the frontend. I'm encountering an issue where I cannot display data from my `notifications` table in a dropdown menu in my `topnavigation.vue` component.

Issue: The notification dropdown is supposed to list notifications, but it's either empty or not updating with new notifications. There are no console errors, and I've confirmed that the backend is sending data correctly.

Here's the relevant part of my `topnavigation.vue`:

```
<div v-if="isNotificationsDropdownOpen" >
     <template v-if="notificationStore.notifications?.length">
        <a v-for="notification in notificationStore.notifications" :key="notification.id">
             A new task has been created/updated for Incident ID:{{ notification.data?.incidentId }} 
        </a>
     </template>
        <a v-else >
             No notifications 
       </a>
     </div>
  </div></template>
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted, onUnmounted } from 'vue';
import { useUserStore } from '@/stores/user/userStore';
import axios from 'axios';
import { initFlowbite } from 'flowbite';
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import { useNotificationStore } from '@/stores/notification/notificationStore';
const route = useRoute();
//other parts of script
const notificationStore = useNotificationStore();
const isNotificationsDropdownOpen = ref(false);
const toggleNotificationsDropdown = () => {
    isNotificationsDropdownOpen.value = !isNotificationsDropdownOpen.value;
};

onMounted(() => {
    notificationStore.loadNotifications();
});
onMounted(() => {
  initFlowbite();
});
</script>
```

And this is my `NotificationStore.ts`:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { state } from './state';
import { getters } from './getters';
import api from '@/api';

export const useNotificationStore = defineStore("notificationStore", {
    state: state,
    getters: getters,
    actions: {
        async loadNotifications() {
            this.loadingNotifications = true;
            await api.getNotifications().then(response => {
                this.notifications = response.data.data;
                return this.notifications;
            }).finally(() => {
                this.loadingNotifications = false;
            });
        },
    },
});
```

and here is my `NotificationModel`:

```
export interface NotificationState {
    notifications: Notification[];
    loadingNotifications:boolean;
}
export interface NotificationData {
    incidentId: number;
    // other fields here
    // ...
}
export interface Notification {
    id?: string;
    type?: string;
    notifiable_type?: string;
    notifiable_id?: number;
    data?: NotificationData;
    read_at?: string;
}
```

I suspect the issue might be related to Vue's reactivity system or the way I'm fetching data, but I'm not sure how to diagnose or fix it. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.